# Find Prime Factor Too Slow or Crashes

Tags: optimization, lisp, common-lisp

I am currently learning LISP by going through some of the problems on ProjectEuler site. One of the problems asks this:

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

I have scrapped together Lisp code that does this. However, for numbers with 9+ digits, it is very slow. Most of the time I never get a solution, whereas for 8 digits, it takes about 4-5 seconds. What's more, sometimes I get "HEAP exceeded" error.

My question is am I doing something wrong in terms of running the code (use Aquamacs)? What are some ways this code can be optimized to be better suited for the task at hand? More importantly, how can "exceeded HEAP" crashes be avoided?

Code:

```
(defun potential-factors (number) 
  (loop for x from 1 to (ceiling (/ number 2)) 
        for y = x 
        collect y))

(defun factors (number) 
  (let (prime-factors '()) 
    (loop for x in (potential-factors number) 
          do (if (= (mod number x) 0) 
                 (setq prime-factors (cons x prime-factors)))) 
    prime-factors))

(defun is-prime (n &optional (d (- n 1))) 
  (if (/= n 1)
      (or (= d 1)
          (and (/= (rem n d) 0)
               (is-prime  n (- d 1)))) ()))

(defun problem-3 (number) 
  (last (sort (remove-if-not #'is-prime (factors number) :from-end t) #'<)))
```

Comment: Google "Sieve of Eratosthenes" for a way to make a list of prime numbers. Then you don't have to do such an expensive search for each potential factor.

Comment: @Barmar very well! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are creating a list in `potential-factors` of all the numbers between 1 and n/2. That list takes a huge amount of memory and causes the program to crash. The good news is that you don't need to accumulate these numbers in a list, but simply use one number at a time. In `factors` replace the line  `(loop for x in (potential-factors number)` with `(loop for x from 1 to (ceiling (/ number 2))`

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no mathematician, but another thought: The insight about dividing n by 2 seems to be that factors come in pairs.  A is a factor of N only if A times B is N, so B has to be at least 2.  But that logic can be extended, right?  What about dividing by 3?  Once you've checked to see if 3 is a factor, then there is no point in checking all numbers greater than 1/3 N.  The same for 4, etc.  The observation would seem to be that you really only need to check the numbers such that A is less than or equal to B -- so then what would the limit of that be?  Well, if A = B, then A times B = A times A, which means that that in that case, A is the square root of N.  So I would think you only need to check up as high as the square root N, instead of all the way up to N / 2.

But I'm no mathematician.

Comment: Yes, this is valid. I actually had this in the original code but then it got re-written somehow. I shall change this to see if it affects the performance by a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think the result of `(potential-factors 600851475143)` is? How long would it take to compute a result and how much memory would the result need?

Comment: As in the largest prime factor result? I suspect it will be about 5-7 digits long.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: what is the result of above function call?